# Get all logical children

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to get all of the logical children in my view (a user control).  I start from the root element, and traverse the logical tree, and everything works as expected, however, several of my child controls are items like ListBox etc. that are data bound and use data templates for their children, and these are the items that are not getting returned in the logical tree.

Here is the code I am using:

```
private static void GetLogicalChildren<T>(DependencyObject parent, List<T> logicalCollection) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        IEnumerable children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent);

        foreach (object child in children)
        {
            if (child is DependencyObject)
            {
                DependencyObject depChild = child as DependencyObject;

                if (child is T)
                {
                    logicalCollection.Add(child as T);
                }

                GetLogicalChildren(depChild, logicalCollection);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The controls rendered by DataTemplates are not in the logical tree, they're in the visual tree. The DataContext objects (Viewmodels probably) to which the DataTemplates are bound are in the logical tree in the Items property.

If you want to get the visual controls contained in child `DataTemplates` you need to look at the visual tree, not the logical tree.

`VisualTreeHelper` has a `GetChild` method and a `ChildCount` property that you can use to iterate through the visual children of your `ItemsControls`